# Cannot find repository from submodule

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

To update my submodules, I use `git submodule update --init --recursive`. For all the submodules, I get an output similar to this:

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found. 

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

However when I clone the repository directly with `git clone`, everything works fine.

My `.gitmodules` file looks like this:

```
[submodule "External/{repo}"]

        path = External/{repo}

        url = ../{repo}
```

I do have the repo cloned in the parent directory, so I know I have access privileges and am able to clone it normally.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Is it exact `.gitmodules` file. I believe by {repo} you mean some real submodule name. If it is so, it looks like you are using [relative url](https://www.gniibe.org/memo/software/git/using-submodule.html) for submodule. In that case please check if you can clone standalone submodule (of course first you have to convert relative path to full repo url). Also it is possible that git user, you are using for cloning, does not have read permission to parent directory of your project remote repo. In that case change `url` in `.gitmodules` file to full url to submodule repo.

Comment: @running.t If I use the full URL, I can clone it into a different location. If I put the same URL in `.gitmodules`, I get the same behavior.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user467384 No, I don't remember what project this was on and I have a similar setup on my current projects and it's working fine. I have had issues in the past with a '/' character as the end of the URL breaking things, that might have been related.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue.

I realized the "/" behind the sub-repo-name.git in the url of the error message. This sounds similar to the last comment of @user467384.

Therfore, I checked my .gitmodules file. But there was no "/" behind the .git. So, I deleted all charackters behind this and it started working.